# Nginx - Redirect url for certain file type

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have nginx 1.2.1. I want to rewrite:

`http://mywebsite.com/[token].mp4` to `http://mywebsite.com/get.php?token=[token]`

Return error 404, my block:

```
location ~* \.(mp4)$ {
    rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{23})\$" /get.php?token=$1 break;
}
```

I tried [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/526409/nginx-rewrite-how-to-redirect-url-for-certain-file-type) but nothing, it returns error 404

Answer (score 3):

According to `nginx.conf` you provided [here](http://pastebin.com/k9ArzCaX), try below:

```
location ^~ /videos/ {
    rewrite "^/videos/([a-zA-Z0-9]{23})\.mp4$" /get.php?token=$1 break;
}
```

This should match URL: `example.com/videos/abc01234567890123456789.mp4` and redirect to `example.com/get.php?token=abc01234567890123456789`

**DISCLAIMER:** config not tested, may have some typos

Comment: I added " " at "^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{23})\.mp4$", otherwise I have the error 
"nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite.com:45". But I'm redirect on the index page now

Comment: Hmm nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" - I tried to replaced ":" by ";", and deleted it, but same thing

Comment: sorry, typo was there, fixed.

Comment: Hmm redirect on index too. It's normal that I'm redirect on the index when I go to http://mywebsite.com/neverexisted ? However my error page is error_page 404 403 http://mywebsite.com/404; I'm only redirected when I put the extension neverexisted.php/html...

Comment: can you post all your config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90935/discussion-between-mergenchik-and-baraque-obahamas).

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try this, if not, I got no more ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try looking at the headers specifically content type like so:

https://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=359